# NERDTree: what does a starred/bold file indicate?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

In NERDTree, what does it mean when a file starred/bold? It seems to happen a lot for me for minified JavaScript files and sometimes for executable shell scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files with stars are executable files. For example, you can check `/usr/bin` directory, you are gonna see almost all files in that directory are starred.

For the bold, the current root is bold. E.g., if you select `/usr/bin/` then type `C`, your current root would be `/usr/bin`, and would be bold right at top of your NERDTree window.

Here I don't see a file name is bold highlighted...

Comment: NERDTree simply uses the same convention as `ls`.

Comment: And if you don't like the highlighting, you can change / disable it, e.g. `:highlight link NERDTreeExecFile ModeMsg`

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks for your comment, could you please explain a bit what does that command do?

Comment: @Tropilio This links the NERDTree syntax group for executable files to a default Vim highlight group; if you use `Normal` instead of `ModeMsg`, there wouldn't be any highlighting.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks! Do you know any way to remove the asterisk which is appended at the end of executable files? (I am a vim user on WSL, and for some reason, in WSL all files in the windows partition are mounted as executables... so it's a bit annoying to see asterisk everywhere in NERDtree!).

Comment: @Tropilio: I'm afraid [that asterisk is hard-coded in the plugin's source code](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/a722613f36d07eb410aac55acfcf2645598e642e/lib/nerdtree/path.vim#L50-L52); you'd have to modify the plugin itself or ask the author to make this configurable.